# How to combine javascript functions?

Tags: javascript

How can I do this, not sure if it is even the right terminology to what I am trying to do. Firstly, can I even do it on the below?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
   .fancybox({
    padding : 0
   });
  });



 $(document).ready(function($) {
var fancyGallery = $("#pichide").find("a");
fancyGallery.attr("rel","gallery2").fancybox({
    type: "image"

});
$('#fancyLaunch').on('click', function() {
    fancyGallery.eq(0).click(); 
});
});
```

Do I have to leave these seperate .ready or is there a way that is more correct to combine  the first part of them. In the second, why would the function break is I add `padding : 0` after type: "image".

Comment: Yes - you can use two `ready`s, or you can use one `ready` that does two things.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you need to be putting each block into a new handler for the document load, you could put it all into one handler;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox")
        .attr('rel', 'gallery')
       .fancybox({
           padding : 0
        });

    var fancyGallery = $("#pichide").find("a");
    fancyGallery.attr("rel","gallery2").fancybox({
        type: "image"
    ...
});
```

Comment: Are you sure this is what the asker is asking? I'm not.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to me to turn your two processes into functions, and call them from the document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    fancyGallery();
    fancybox();
});


function fancyGallery() {
    var fancyGallery = $("#pichide").find("a");
    fancyGallery.attr("rel","gallery2").fancybox({
        type: "image"
    });
    $('#fancyLaunch').on('click', function() {
        fancyGallery.eq(0).click(); 
    });
}

function fancyBox() {
    $(".fancybox")
        .attr('rel', 'gallery')
        .fancybox({
        padding : 0
    });
}
```